# catchbackkey not working (libgdx) Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to use the back key on the android device to setscreens for my game..But it does'nt seem to work..
I read few posts online n did this...

In the menuscreen if the backkey is pressed the app should exit..But no action is triggered...Even if i press the back key numerous no action is triggered...

```
public class MenuScreen extends AbstractScreen implements InputProcessor  {

@Override
   public void show()
   {
      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
      Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
      Gdx.input.setCatchMenuKey(true);

}


   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK)
        { 
             Gdx.app.exit();
          }

      return false;
   }
```

In LevelScreen when the back key is pressed the screen should set to menuscreen , but my application will quit 
Is there way to disable the back key ??Nothing should happen if its pressed ?

```
  public class LevelScreen extends AbstractScreen  implements InputProcessor {

@Override
   public void show()
   {
      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
      Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
      Gdx.input.setCatchMenuKey(true);

}

@Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
      if(keycode == Keys.BACK)
      {
                game.setScreen(game.geMenuScreen());
           }
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Could please post what version of android the device is using, and what version of libgdx you are using?

Comment: I tried it on  emulator and phone with android 2.3.3...

Using 0.9.6 libgdx...

Comment: Silly question, but why are you catching the back key from the menu screen if you want it to exit from that screen?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you probably want to change it from using keyDown() to keyUp() in the input processor. keyUp() will only be called once when the user releases the key, but keyDown() will be called every frame the back key was down (roughly 60 times a second). So your app could switch screens and close on you in 2 frames which likely isn't what you want.

This is likely why you see the app close from the level screen. It will be going LevelScreen -> ScoreScreen -> MenuScreen and then quitting in 3 frames (roughly 50 milliseconds). Here is some sample code of an application which starts in a ScoreScreen. When the user presses (and releases) the back button goes to the menu screen. Next, when they press (and release) the back button again it then closes the application.

You will need to adapt this code to your game, but this should give you something to look at and work with. (Note: I have verified this working on Android 2.3.3 and LibGDX 0.9.8)

```
public class BackTest extends Game {
    public Screen menu;
    public Screen score;

    @Override public void create() {
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
        this.menu = new MenuScreen(this);
        this.score = new ScoreScreen(this);
        this.setScreen(this.score);
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractScreen implements Screen {
        @Override public void render(final float delta) {}
        @Override public void resize(final int width, final int height) {}
        @Override public void show() {}
        @Override public void hide() {}
        @Override public void pause() {}
        @Override public void resume() {}
        @Override public void dispose() {}
    }

    public static class MenuScreen extends AbstractScreen {
        public final BackTest game;

        public MenuScreen(final BackTest game) {
            this.game = game;
        }

        @Override public void show() {
            Gdx.app.log("Menu", "Show");
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
                @Override public boolean keyUp(final int keycode) {
                    if (keycode == Keys.BACK) {
                        Gdx.app.log("Menu", "Quit");
                        Gdx.app.exit();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static class ScoreScreen extends AbstractScreen {
        public final BackTest game;

        public ScoreScreen(final BackTest game) {
            this.game = game;
        }

        @Override public void show() {
            Gdx.app.log("Score", "Show");
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
                @Override public boolean keyUp(final int keycode) {
                    if (keycode == Keys.BACK) {
                        Gdx.app.log("Score", "Back");
                        ScoreScreen.this.game.setScreen(ScoreScreen.this.game.menu);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried key Up , No use..
Actually the back key in not even working in MenuScreen..
If i press the back button on the levelscreen , the game closes..If i restart it , the textures are not loaded properly..ill have to force close it and open again..

Comment: Textures need to be reloaded when you go back into the app. As for the  back key, I can't see why it wouldn't work with the code you posted. Could you post a bit more complete version of your code so I can see if there is something else?

Comment: There's nothing else in the code..Just i have added few actors , table and buttons..
I did a mistake in my op..If backkey is pressed in lvelscreen it should go to menuscreen not highscorescreen like i had posted ..The back does'nt work in menu screen and in highscores screen also..it just works in level screen , but it minimizes the app..Also can you tell me how to reload the textures ?

n thanks a lot of answering the questions

Comment: For reloading textures take a look at the AssetManager, if you have any more questions about that you should make a new question on stackoverflow :).

Comment: My only suggestion for you with the back button is to make sure you are actually calling the correct inputprocessor (put a Gdx.app.log inside the key methods to see which one is being called)

Comment: I added log statements like you said and ran it on desktop..
Neither keydown nor key up log statements are displaying..So i guess the keydown and keyup code is not at all running right ??

Comment: Double check where you are calling Gdx.input.setInputProcessor and make sure you are setting the input processor to the one you want.

Comment: No problem, glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You should @Override keyUp button instead.

```
@Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        if ((state == SETTING_STATE || state == TOPSCORES_STATE) && keycode == Keys.BACK) {
            state = RUNNING_STATE;
            is_game_start = true;
        } else {
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
        return false;
    }
```