# Libgdx android back button exit app

Tags: libgdx

I'm using libgdx in my game and I want to catch android back button. 
I want this scenario: 
I have three screens: `Screen1, Screen2` and `Screen3`. When I'm on Screen3 and I press back button on android I want to open Screen2 screen, but in my case all app exit (Closes all sceens 1,2 and 3). I'm using this code:

```
    @Override
    public void show() {

        backButtonPressed = false;
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
     }


    @Override
    public void hide() {
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK) && !backButtonPressed){
            ScreenTransition transition = ScreenTransitionFade.init(0.5f);// init(0.5f, ScreenTransitionSlice.UP_DOWN, 10, Interpolation.pow5Out);
            game.setScreen(new Screen2(), transition);
            backButtonPressed = true;
        }
}
```

The same code in Screen3 and Screen2 `(new Screen1() and new Screen2())`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [catchbackkey not working (libgdx) Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15719936/139530) for the solution - the short version is that you should be hooking isKeyUp